# deploying ionic app to EKS not loading website after deployment

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a simple ionic web app that I need deployed to EKS. I believe the deployment is done but I can't access teh website with its EXTERNAL_IP.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install -g @ionic/cli
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
RUN  ionic build
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/www /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN chown root /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN chmod 755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# Start
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
}
```

and my eks deployment file is simple:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: appshop
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: appshop
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app :  appshop
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: appshop
          image: makin/app-shop
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: us-east-2
            - name: AWS_PROFILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: AWS_PROFILE

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: appshop-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: appshop
```

when I try to open the app, there is no response. What am I doing wrong? Is targetPort:80 correct since I want to access the web server which listens on 80?

logs of the pod show:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Comment: What does "no response" mean for you? Do you mean "empty response" or "connection timeout"

Comment: Also, don't use "server_name localhost" in nginx config file. Use "server_name _" (underscore).

Comment: @Matt thanks I am getting This page isn’t workingac911e3d1d78e4037a41dac5f8ac5675-657574225.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Check the logs of appshop pod for erros. Is there enything suspicious.

Comment: @Matt logs are added to the question and thanks again.

Comment: Well, these are not very helpful. Can you exec to the appshop pod and `curl localhost`?